# How can I dynamically create (or fake) a <th> cell using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am using Javascript to dynamically create a table, and want to make a header-style cell at the beginning of each row.  So my question is how I can do this, seeing as `insertCell` creates only a normal `<td>` element and not a `<th>`.

Some things I've tried (via the Tryit editor at w3schools; I have no reason to suspect that any other usage will behave differently) and didn't work:

- I've seen a suggestion to create the `<th>` element independently and then add it to the `<tr>` element as a child.  When I do this, however, it is not added as a table cell, i.e. it is not affected by the table border, does not count toward the array of cells (i.e. if you do `insertCell(1)`, it inserts after the first cell not counting the `<th>`), and does not get the special bold/center format for a `<th>` cell.
- I've attempted to use `insertCell` to make a dummy cell and then `replaceChild` with an independently created  cell; this had the same result as above.
- I've tried to make a `<td>` cell via insertCell and simply bold and center it manually, but `myCell.style.fontWeight="bold"` and `myCell.align="center"` don't seem to work (they just end the function, as bad commands do in JavaScript), and likewise trying to use CSS doesn't work.  So maybe I just have bad syntax or something, but I've got no clue what to do.  Any help would be appreciated.

Attempt 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to insert new cell(s) at the end of the table row.</p>

<table border="1">
  <th>1</th>
  <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="myRow">
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table><br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>


function myFunction()
{
var newRow = document.getElementById("myRow");
    var header=document.createElement("th").appendChild(document.createTextNode("a"));
newRow.appendChild(header);
    var enablesLoc=newRow.insertCell(0).appendChild(document.createTextNode("b"));

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Result: "1" is bolded with a border, "2" and "b" are unbolded with a border (as they should be), "a" is unbolded with no border.

Attempt 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to insert new cell(s) at the end of the table row.</p>

<table border="1">
  <th>1</th>
  <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="myRow">
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table><br>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>


function myFunction()
{
var newRow = document.getElementById("myRow");
var header=newRow.insertCell(0).appendChild(document.createTextNode("a"));
header.style.fontWeight="bold";
var enablesLoc=newRow.insertCell(1).appendChild(document.createTextNode("b"));

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Result: The button adds cell "a" unbolded but not cell "b".

Comment: `document.createElement("th")`, for all your element-creating needs.

Comment: Thank you, I know how to create the element; the problem is that I don't know how to add it to the table row as a cell; addChild and replaceChild add it, but not as a table cell.

Comment: @user1837296 `parentElement.appendChild(returnValueOf_createElement)`

Comment: `appendChild` (not `addChild`) on the row, not the entire table. Also, “they just end the function, as bad commands do in JavaScript” is not correct and you should check your console. Also also, if you’re using W3Schools as a resource, be warned that it’s not a very good one.

Comment: Please show your existing JavaScript. It's easier for us to help by adding to or fixing your existing code rather than doing the whole thing from scratch.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @ minitech: You are correct that I miswrote; I used appendChild.  My experience has been that bad commands cause the script to stop working.  And I'm aware that W3Schools has problems, but I don't remember hearing that that extended to their tester.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I will add my existing code in an edit to the question shortly.

Comment: @nnnnnn I've edited the question to include my two main attempts; if you can identify what I'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here are all the DOM 2 HTML methods, including `insertCell()`: http://objjob.phrogz.net/html/methods Formally defined at: http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-70313345

Comment: _"W3Schools has problems, but I don't remember hearing that that extended to their tester"_ - W3Schools seems to be trying to make money dishonestly: they pretend to be associated with the W3C when they are not, so people who are fooled by this use their resources and contribute to their ad revenue. Plus they _sell_ worthless "certifications" - I don't know how that could be described as anything but a scam. Therefore even in the cases where they have useful tools _any_ use of their site at all is going to contribute to their profits by helping them to get advertisers, etc.

Comment: @ Phrogz: Thank you, but createTHead creates a header for the entire table, not a header cell.  @nnnnnn ok, I've tried it in jsfiddle, and gotten the same result.  I'm still waiting to see if anyone actually can help me, even by telling me how I can bold and center a table cell.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree - What needs elaboration: I explicitly applied the word "scam" to the certifications. They _charge money_ for a product that is _worthless._ W3Schools promotes these certificates as something that will help your career, but no employer with a clue will give them any weight. And, again, W3Schools _charges money for them._ How is that not dishonest? (Regarding the w3 in their name, I think this is intended to create the impression they are associated with or endorsed by the actual w3c. They certainly don't make it clear that they're not associated.)

Comment: @user1837296: I updated my answer. Please let me know if you have further questions or if my update solved the issue for you.

Comment: @user1837296 for your information the html structure of the table in  attempt 2 is not correct.

Answer (score 4):

The following code shows everything that should get you going:

```
function addTable(){
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerText = "im a td";
    th.innerText = "im a th";
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(tr);
    var out = document.getElementById("out");
    out.appendChild(table);
}
```

You have to call the function and an div with id out `<div id=out>...</div>` must be in the document. **Disclaimer: i only tested this code in chrome**

### Update to address your points

You wrote `I've seen a suggestion to create the <th> element independently and then add it to the <tr> element as a child. When I do this`

- `it is not added as a table cell` what do you mean by that and what command are you using,
- `is not affected by the table border` the reason could be because it contains not text,
- `does not count toward the array of cells (i.e. if you do insertCell(1)` i do not understand this either. According to the specs on [insertCell](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-68927016) it insert an empty `td` and returns a reference. So insertCell has no array, If you try `var table = document.getElementById("myTable")` and then  `table.rows[0].cells.length` it returns the number of cells including the `th`-cell.
- `it inserts after the  first cell not counting the th` according on my tests at least in chrome  this is not the case; it depends on how you call the method: `table.rows[1].insertCell(-1);` adds a cell at the second row (zero based array) at the end and `table.rows[2].insertCell(1);` adds in the third row a cell on position 2 (again zero based) if you use `table.rows[3].insertCell(0);` the cell is inserted into the 4th. row at the beginning,
- `and does not get the special bold/center format for a th cell` this was not the case for me as well

**Disclaimer: i only tested this code in chrome**

The html

```
<button onclick="addRow()">add rows</button><br />
<button onclick="addColumn()">add column</button>

<table border="1" id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the javascript

```
function addRow()
{    
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerText = "im a td";
    th.innerText = "im a th";
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(tr);    
}

function addColumn(){
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var rows = table.rows;
    console.log("rows", rows);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {                
        // td = rows[i].cells;
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerText = i;
        rows[i].appendChild(td);    
    }       
}
```

Based on **[DOM Level 2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/def-index.html)** you can not use `insertCell` since it  `Insert[s] an empty TD cell into this row`. But you want to add a `th`
According to **[DOM Level 3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107)** you can use `appendChild` since it `adds the node newChild to the end of the list of children of this node. If the newChild is already in the tree, it is first removed.`

So therefore you have to create the elements in the right order: create the row, add the first cell as `th` then add other cells as `td` by using append child.

You may take a look at **[a demo of the above code](http://plnkr.co/edit/LxfQMCJ7VcohSMpkYhrp?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

The [`.appendChild()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) returns the element being appended. Which means on this line:

```
var header=document.createElement("th").appendChild(document.createTextNode("a"));
```

...your `header` variable is actually the text node, not the th element - so then `newRow.appendChild(header);` appends just the text node to the row, not the new th.

Try something like this instead:

```
var newRow = document.getElementById("myRow");
var header = document.createElement("th");
header.appendChild(document.createTextNode("a"));
newRow.appendChild(header);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PtzRL/

Note that if you actually want to append new rows then your `newRow` variable should not be getting a reference to an existing row in the table, you should give an id to the table:

```
<table id="myTable">
```

...and then create a new row and add that to the table:

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
table.appendChild(newRow);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PtzRL/1/

(Note also that the starting html you show has an error: you're missing the first `<tr>` just after the `<table>` tag, and you have an extra `<tr>` just before the closing `</table>` tag.)

Comment: Thank you.  That not only works, it explains what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were trying to do?

```
function myFunction = function() {    
    var newRow, newHeader, newCell;
    newRow = document.getElementById("myRow");

    newHeader = document.createElement("th");
    newHeader.innerText = "a";
    newRow.appendChild(newHeader);

    newCell = document.createElement("td");
    newCell.innerText = "b";
    newRow.appendChild(newCell);
}
```

If you want the button to add new rows rather than filling in a blank row you put there already, try something like this:
HTML:

```
<body>
    <table id="myTable" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction = function() {    
    var myTable, newRow, newHeader, newCell;
    myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
    newRow = document.createElement("tr");

    newHeader = document.createElement("th");
    newHeader.innerText = "a";
    newRow.appendChild(newHeader);

    newCell = document.createElement("td");
    newCell.innerText = "b";
    newRow.appendChild(newCell);

    myTable.appendChild(newRow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function need to altered like this I believe...

```
function myFunction()
{
var newRow = document.getElementById("myRow");
    var header=document.createElement("th");
header.appendChild(document.createTextNode("a"));
newRow.appendChild(header);
    var enablesLoc=newRow.insertCell(0);
enables.appendChild(document.createTextNode("b"));

}
```